# Viewing Example functions with `go doc` command?

Tags: go, godoc

If I view a package's documentation via the web at https://pkg.go.dev, the page includes `Example` test functions. The output of `go doc -u -all` for a package does not. Is it possible to have such information included?

Comment: It is not possible to display examples using the `go doc` command. The command implementation ignores examples.

Comment: Thank you, @CeriseLimón. That seemed to be the case, but I was holding out hope. I don't mean to generate work for you, but would you consider turning your comment into an answer?

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26715

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to display examples using the `go doc` command.

The [command implementation](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/cmd/doc) ignores examples.

Answer (score 1):

Godoc examples are snippets of Go code that are displayed as package documentation and that are verified by running them as tests. They can also be run by a user visiting the godoc web page for the package and clicking the associated “Run” button

https://go.dev/blog/examples

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I really wanted was just to see the examples in the terminal output—just like the rest of the go documentation, but I guess the `go doc` command does not allow this.

Answer (score 0):

I installed godoc with:

```
go install -v golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc@latest
```

And examples (if correctly named) are shown for me. I think you should correctly name your example functions in tests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a good answer, but not what I wanted, which was just to see the examples in the terminal, not in my browser.